# How to authenticate with OIDC in JasperReports using Web Service Datasource?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, openid-connect, jasperserver, keycloak

We are using [web service datasource](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source) to interact with REST data in Jasper Reports.

That Web Service data source has 2 methods of authentication:

1. Basic
2. Google Authentication key

So we cannot query it with our actual security implementation.

**Security description:**

We are using `keycloak` and [`Open ID Connect`](http://openid.net/connect/) protocol for protecting the endpoints. 
Therefore, if we would like to query `http://<host>:<port>/endpoint` we need to have signed `JSON Web Token`on the client **(jasper server)** side to access it.

Did somebody already had this issue?

Is it possible to solve it without modification in Web Service plugin source code?

Used JasperReports Server version: `6.4.2`